# How do you use Tensorflow Keras Custom Objects with tf.saved_model.Asset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have a custom Keras Layer that reads from a pickle file to initialize some weights, and I'd like to be able to use `tf.keras.utils.register_keras_serializable()` on it. The issue is that my `__init__` function takes the path to the pickle file, which might not be available when the layer is deserialized again. Keras [Assets](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/Asset) should theoretically make the layer more portable, but I can't figure out how to get it to work with the layer's `get_config()`.

Barebones version of my code:

```
@tf.keras.utils.register_keras_serializable()
class AssetLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, asset_path, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.asset_path = asset_path
        self.asset = tf.saved_model.Asset(asset_path)
        data = tf.io.read_file(self.asset)
        # do something with data

    def get_config(self):
        return {
            **super().get_config(),
            "asset_path": self.asset_path,
        }

    def call(self, arg):
        # arbitrary call function
        return arg
```

If a model using this layer is loaded using `tf.keras.models.load_model()`, Keras will call `get_config()` to reinitialize the layer using the saved `asset_path` which might not be pointing to the right place at deserialization time. Ideally it would point to the path of the saved asset, but I don't know how to make it do that.

For instance, I've tried this code

```
!echo abcd > file.txt
model = tf.keras.Sequential([AssetLayer("file.txt")])
model(tf.ones(3))
model.save("test")

# reloading
!rm file.txt
reloaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("test")
```

which gives me an error saying `file.txt` is not found.

I've also tried removing the `get_config()` function entirely. This makes it so the layer can be successfully reloaded while retaining access to the `asset` variable, but other attributes in the layer such as `self.asset_path` aren't accessible. This isn't ideal for debugging purposes, so I'm wondering if there's a better way.

I'm currently using Tensorflow 2.5.0`

Answer (score 0):

**Edited code:**
Previous to this part , code is fine .Issue is replicating because of

```
!rm file.txt
```

(so I put it at the end)

```
!echo abcd > file.txt
model = tf.keras.Sequential([AssetLayer("file.txt")])
model(tf.ones(3))
model.save("./content/sample_data/test.h5")

# reloading

reloaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("/content/content/sample_data/test.h5")
reloaded_model.summary()
!rm file.txt
```

Reference: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize

Comment: Removing the `file.txt` is the whole point because we want our model to be portable. If our model depends on the asset `file.txt`, we want to be sure that we can reload the model in a new environment where that file doesn't exist. The SavedModel format does save a copy of `file.txt` in its exported data, so it should theoretically be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

It seems "tf.saved_model.Asset" do not support "tf.keras.models.load_model"
Try use tf.saved_model.save / tf.saved_model.load instead